# Using an API, variable being returned that is not a string/int or anything and can't be written to in a messagebox

Tags: c#, json, api, var

Here is the variable that is being returned (literally a var):
!http://goo.gl/cphlPz
Here is the path from that method in the API source:
http://puu.sh/6H8sE.png

I have 0 rep so I can't put pics, but I used googles url thing to post them. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: what is the real question here, how to display your `tiersum1` in message box?

Comment: If tiersum1 is a LeagueDto object, just go like tiersum1.Name or whatever u want to show.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to see a text representation of the content of the returned dictionary. In that case, you can implement a corresponding ToString method in your LeagueResult class and call that ToString() method on your variable.

There is no default implementation for ToString() on dictionary, and no overload of MessageBox.Show which would take an object.